# Расположение виджетов QT Designer?

Tags: python, qt-designer

Как в QT Designer сделать контейнер в котором элементы при растягивании окна будут заполняться по сетке как на скриншотах?

1. Изначальное расположение элементов

[image: Изначальное расположение элементов]

2. Как должно получиться после растягивания окна

[image: Расположение элементов после растягивания окна]

Comment: Вы задания получаете или раздаете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо большое, не мог найти

Comment: Евгений пожалуйста. Дерзайте.